# NOT EXIST between Postgres and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, not-exists

I have 2 server, the server1 (PostgreSQL) is our integrator and the server2 (Azure SQL Server) is for our enterprise.

So I try to extract tables from server1 and copy them to server2 for our ETL.

To not do that every day, I want to extract only rows that I don't already extract. In terms of SQL code, I try to do something like that:

```
select * 
from server1.database1.MyTable
where not exists (select * from server2.database2.Mytable)
```

The issue is this SQL query doesn't work, I get this error:

> SQL Error [40515] [S0001]: Reference to database and/or server name in 'server1.database1.MyTable' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it a single Azure SQL Database?, or is it a managed instance?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `NOT EXISTS`. The error is specific to what the problem is, that you cannot server/database qualify a table. Not sure how you expect to use two different servers in one query anyway?

Comment: @Lamak, Not it's not the same Database. The server1 PostgreSQL (produce by someone else) and server2 is Azur SQL Server (Our Database). Then to analyse our data, we need to copy all table everyday in our ETL

Comment: No, I get that, I'm asking if the resource you have in azure is a single Azure SQL Database or is a managed instance?. With single azure sql database you can't use a SELECT to another database in the same server, even less so to another server

Comment: @Lamak, Ha sorry, yes it's a single Azure SQL Database! Do you know a workaround for this issue?

Comment: FDW(Foreign Data Wrapper) in particular [tds_fdw](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw).

Comment: Think your missing Transform and Load part of the ETL, either use SSIS or a code layer (e.g. c#) that reads from one server transforms if needed and then saves into the other database.

Comment: I Actually use SSIS. I need to copy every day all tables from the source to put them in my ETL. I want to limit the row I copy (hope that will reduce the time process). I try to use SQL query in SSIS, at the beginning of the process (Source to ODS). The lookup functionality does the work but the SQL Query is better so I try to make it possible between 2 servers.